# comparing two files byte-wise

Tags: c++, qt

Here http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/94032/ I found a great and fast method to compare two files byte-wise. But it has boost dependency. I am now working on a program in Qt. Is there a similarly elegant and/or comparably fast way in pure Qt? Or is there any other algorithm for comparing two files in Qt? I do not insist on using memory mapping...

This is the boost version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>
namespace io = boost::iostreams;
int main()
{
    io::mapped_file_source f1("test.1");
    io::mapped_file_source f2("test.2");

    if(f1.size() == f2.size() && std::equal(f1.data(), f1.data() + f1.size(), f2.data()))
        std::cout << "The files are equal\n";
    else
        std::cout << "The files are not equal\n";
}
```

Comment: See http://blog.qt.io/blog/2007/10/15/file-mapping/

Comment: Definitely elegant. Good luck if your files are 500GB big.

Comment: This is much a OS operation to do. osx and linux have the `cmp` command (here is the source in C: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gnudiff/gnudiff-10/diffutils/cmp.c?txt)

Comment: I've also found something interesting: http://aass.oru.se/~tpy/texts/surprising-compare/index.html

Answer (score 2):

The obvious approach can be made fast although I fear most standard libraries don't make it fast:

```
std::locale::global(std::locale::classic());
std::ifstream f1("test.1");
std::ifstream f2("test.2");
typedef std::istreambuf_iterator<char> isbuf_it;
if (std::equal(isbuf_it(f1.rdbuf()), isbuf_it(),
               isbuf_it(f2.rdbuf()), isbuf_it())) {
    std::cout << "The files are equal\n";
}
else {
    std::cout << "The files are not equal\n";
}
```

Whether that is fast may depend on the standard library optimizing the algorithms for segmented iteration. On the other hand, since the read memory is fresh in cache and accessed just once, there is a fair chance that even without any segmentation optimization each page is processed before the next one is readily read. It is a long time since I benchmarked this kind of stuff...

Comment: @bers Seems I forgot the `<char>` on the iterator (will fix shortly).